# How to extract a Record from a Generic Dictionary?

Tags: f#

Through some API i get access to kind of Table in the form of a sequence of Gereric.Dictionary. Because the table has a schema I want to extract records out of it. Here is what i have ?

```
open System.Collections.Generic

let gd = Dictionary<string,obj> ()
gd.Add("name", "Frank")
gd.Add("age", 24)
gd.Add("born", 1999)

type Person = { name : string
                age  : int}

let extractPerson (gd:Dictionary<string,obj>) = 
 { name = gd.["name"] :?> string
   age  = gd.["age"] :?> int}
```

Can I make the function `extractPerson` more generic, like

```
let extract<'T> (gd:Dictionary<string,obj>) =
  // ???
```

so that I can call ?

```
extract<Person> gd
```

Comment: How would `extract<'T>` work? Are you after a way to use each key in the dictionary to set a property of the same name on the record?

Comment: Yes,  just fill the record with the matching keys from the dictionary

Comment: F# is statically typed, so you will have to use something like reflection or the [DLR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic/) to to this. If you know the list of key's at compile time, you could look into code generation or type-providers (I doubt there's one out of the box for this though).

Comment: Not an easy one, it seems to me. Assuming `'T` must be a record, I would try to solve it by going via reflection through all fields in `'T`, read out the fields from your dict, collect them in an array of objects, then you'd have to call the record constructor. Things are easier if your `'T` has settable properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is something that can only be done using reflection. The following works for your simple example, but it is very limited:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let extract<'T>(gd:Dictionary<string,obj>) = 
  let flds = FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<'T>)
  let vals = [| for f in flds -> gd.[f.Name] |]
  FSharpValue.MakeRecord(typeof<'T>, vals) :?> 'T
```

It uses `GetRecordFields` to find out what the names of the fields are, then it gets their values from the dictionary and calls `MakeRecord` to create the record value. This is not super efficient, but depending on what you need, it might just work good enough for you.

Now you can use it as follows:

```
let gd = Dictionary<string,obj> ()
gd.Add("name", "Frank")
gd.Add("age", 24)
gd.Add("born", 1999)

type Person = { name : string; age  : int}    
extract<Person> gd
```

Comment: Thank you all this big help. To me it looks like this will work for all record types, Do you mean limited according to performance?

Comment: I think it is limited in the sense that there are possibly lot more features you might need to make this practical - how about nested records? what if the value is `int` but your record expects `float`? etc. but for the basics, this does the trick.